# error: constructor AcceptedFriendAction in class AcceptedFriendAction cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java

When I compile my code, I've this error message : "error: constructor AcceptedFriendAction in class AcceptedFriendAction cannot be applied to given types;" at line 23 ( AcceptedFriendAction action [...] )

I read that because I have a String in my constructor, but I don't realy understand how arrange this. If anyone can help me ? Thank you for your time and your comprehension.

```
public class AcceptedFriendAction extends SocialAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -692737;

    @ManyToOne
    private User newFriend;

    public AcceptedFriendAction(final SocialInterest socialInterest,
            final DateTime date, final String suggestComment, final User newFriend) {
    super(socialInterest, date, suggestComment);
    this.newFriend = newFriend;
    }

    public User getNewFriend() {
        return newFriend;
    }

    public static AcceptedFriendAction add(final SocialInterest socialInterest, 
            final String suggestComment, final User newFriend) {

        AcceptedFriendAction action = new AcceptedFriendAction(socialInterest, new DateTime(), newFriend, suggestComment);
        action.save();
        return action;
    }
}
```

thank you again :)

Comment: Read your code once again, and see if the order of passed argument matches the one that the constructor accepts.

Comment: Yeah I'm stupid, I know ... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misplaced 3rd and 4th parameters

Code should look like:

```
AcceptedFriendAction action = new AcceptedFriendAction(socialInterest, new DateTime(), suggestComment, newFriend);
```

Comment: Oh my gaad '-- Thank you very much